# Instantiate application with a Token in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm fairly new to Elixir and I want to write a wrapper around an API to get to know the language, I'm thinking of the way that people with get authenticated to use the API, they need a token obviously but how can I go to authenticate the user? For example, in many languages you do: `Api.Client.new("token")` or something similar, I've been searching some API wrappers in Github to see how people implement those and some use `start_link`, others say that you should use `export API_KEY="api-key"`, others put the key in the `config/config.ex` file, so, I see that using the `config` file is the easiest one or should I do something else? I'm honestly a bit lost in this one.

Comment: To get started, put your keys in `config/`. You can pair that with shell env keys to make it more secure.

Comment: @Sheharyar yes, I have them there in their respective files, I saw some other repos and I'm going to do that. I didn't know that all env variables go in there.